# Why/how does iterating over a list and calling 'pass' each time fix this function?

Tags: python, django

I have written the following function:

```
def auto_update_ratings(amounts, assessment_entries_qs, lowest_rating=-1):
    start = 0
    rating = lowest_rating
    ids = assessment_entries_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)

    for i in ids: # I have absolutely no idea why this seems to be required:
        pass      # without this loop, the last AssessmentEntries fail to update 
                  # in the following for loop.

    for amount in amounts:
        end_mark = start + amount
        entries = ids[start:end_mark]
        a = assessment_entries_qs.filter(id__in=entries).update(rating=rating)
        start = end_mark
        rating += 1
```

It does what it is supposed to do (i.e. update the relevant number of entries in `assessment_entries_qs` with each rating (starting at `lowest_rating`) as specified in `amounts`). Here is a simple example:

```
>>> assessment_entries = AssessmentEntry.objects.all()
>>> print [ae.rating for ae in assessment_entries]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
>>> auto_update_ratings((2,4,3,1), assessment_entries, 1)
>>> print [ae.rating for ae in assessment_entries]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

However, if I do not iterate through `ids` before iterating through `amounts`, the function only updates a subset of the queryset: with my current test data (approximately 250 `AssessmentEntries` in the queryset), it always results in exactly 84 `AssessmentEntries` not being updated.

Interestingly, it is always the last iteration of the second for loop that does not result in any updates (although the rest of the code in that iteration does execute properly), *as well as a portion of the previous iteration*. The querysets are ordered_by('?') prior to being passed to this function, and the intended results are achieved if I simply add the previous 'empty' for loop, so it does not appear to be an issue with my data).

A few more details, just in case they prove to be relevant:

- `AssessmentEntry.rating` is a standard `IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)`.
- I am using this function purely for testing purposes, so I have only been executing it from iPython.
- Test database is SQLite.

**Question:** Can someone please explain why I appear to need to iterate through `ids`, despite not actually touching the data in any way, and why without doing so the function still (sort of) executes correctly, but always fails to update the last few items in the queryset despite apparently still iterating through them?

Comment: disclaimer: i don't know django.  try tailing the database server's log to see what SQL is executed, and when. some ORMs return generators or proxies to a SQL action.  the loop might be necessary to create the objects.  what happens if you add an `all()` to the first query ?  i'd guess that might make the loop unnecessary by forcing an database interaction -- most ORMs want to see an all/first/one action.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, adding `.all()` to the first query has no apparent effect. I believe it is implicit in [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: @JonathanVanasco, in the Django ORM `all()` just returns a copy of the query proxy object--it does not force execution of the query it represents.

Comment: @FrancisAvila thanks. is there a command in django to force the execution? i've barely touched django, but am curious. NEVERMIND.  i see the `list(query)` suggestion below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QuerySets and QuerySet slicing are evaluated *lazily*. Iterating ids executes the query and makes `ids` behave like a static list instead of a QuerySet. So when you loop through `ids`, it causes `entries` later on to be a fixed set of values; but if you *don't* loop through `ids`, then `entries` is just a subquery with a `LIMIT` clause added to represent the slicing you do.

Here is what is happening in detail:

```
def auto_update_ratings(amounts, assessment_entries_qs, lowest_rating=-1):
    # assessment_entries_qs is an unevaluated QuerySet
    # from your calling code, it would probably generate a query like this:
    # SELECT * FROM assessments ORDER BY RANDOM()
    start = 0
    rating = lowest_rating
    ids = assessment_entries_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)
    # ids is a ValueQuerySet that adds "SELECT id"
    # to the query that assessment_entries_qs would generate.
    # So ids is now something like:
    # SELECT id FROM assessments ORDER BY RANDOM()

    # we omit the loop

    for amount in amounts:
        end_mark = start + amount
        entries = ids[start:end_mark]
        # entries is now another QuerySet with a LIMIT clause added:
        # SELECT id FROM assessments ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT start,(start+end_mark)
        # When filter() gets a QuerySet, it adds a subquery
        a = assessment_entries_qs.filter(id__in=entries).update(rating=rating)
        # FINALLY, we now actually EXECUTE a query which is something like this:
        # UPDATE assessments SET rating=? WHERE id IN 
        # (SELECT id FROM assessments ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT start,(start+end_mark))
        start = end_mark
        rating += 1
```

Since the subquery in `entries` is executed *every time you insert* and it has a random order, the slicing you do is meaningless! This function does not have deterministic behavior.

However when you iterate ids you actually execute the query, so your slicing has deterministic behavior again and the code does what you expect.

Let's see what happens when you use a loop instead:

```
ids = assessment_entries_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)

# Iterating ids causes the query to actually be executed
# This query was sent to the DB:
# SELECT id FROM assessments ORDER BY RANDOM()
for id in ids:
    pass

# ids has now been "realized" and contains the *results* of the query
# e.g., [5,1,2,3,4]
# Iterating again (or slicing) will now return values rather than modify the query

for amount in amounts:
    end_mark = start + amount
    entries = ids[start:end_mark]
    # because ids was executed, entries contains definite values
    # When filter() gets actual values, it adds a simple condition
    a = assessment_entries_qs.filter(id__in=entries).update(rating=rating)
    # The query executed is something like this:
    # UPDATE assessments SET rating=? WHERE id IN (5,1)
    # "(5,1)" will change on each iteration, but it will always be a set of
    # scalar values rather than a subquery.
    start = end_mark
    rating += 1
```

If you ever need to eagerly evaluate a QuerySet to get all its values at a moment in time, rather than perform a do-nothing iteration just convert it to a list:

```
    ids = list(assessment_entries_qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Also the Django docs go into detail about [when exactly a `QuerySet` is evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and converting to a list does indeed solve the problem, but I still don't understand why I always end up with exactly the same number of non-updated entries, and why it is always the last iteration of the second for loop that does not result in any updates (as well as a few from the previous iteration). In fact, by default, the last two values in `amounts` tend to be the two largest values in the tuple, so if anything I would expect _more_ of them to update.

Comment: Great explanation! But one question: the second time `ids[start:end_mark]` is evaluated, is the LIMIT clause redefined and the query reexecuted? Or is it a normal splice on the results of the previous result?

Comment: @rodrigo, It is a normal slice on the previously-retrieved results. The query is not re-executed.

Comment: @ojh, since you are taking a slice of a query that returns results in a random order, all bets are off. The rows you end up updating are random. In fact, you are probably updating some of the same rows multiple times.

Comment: @FrancisAvila, yeah, that's the part I don't understand: every single time I run the code without first converting `ids` to a static list, it results in exactly the same number of items not being updated each time (e.g. if I set all ratings to `None` before starting, I always end up with exactly 84 `None` ratings at the end (out of a total of 239 AssessmentEntries))!

Comment: Sqlite's `random()` function is a pseudo-random number generator, so perhaps the behavior is random but deterministic.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Actually, it would be better to say that the behavior is not random but _arbitrary_. The unpredictability of the order is not done on purpose to create entropy, it is simple the result of using internal, unspecified algorithms, that may change any time for any reason. The fact that differents runs of the same query over the same data gives the same order, although not guaranteed, is quite expected.

Comment: @rodrigo, @FrancisAvila: I'm still not sure why none of the ratings were being rated 5 and the amount of entries rated 4 was not equal to `amounts[-2]` (when `amounts` was a tuple containing 7 integers), but perhaps that is a separate issue that just happens to also get solved by this? Either way, thanks to both of you for helping to clear this up for me!